# Perl one-liner to specify decimal places

Tags: perl

I'm modifying a large txt file. Is there a one-liner in which you pad a string pattern to the right with zeros? For instance, to go from one or two decimal places to three. e.g. from 0.21 to 0.210 or 0.5 to 0.500? The code I was trying:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(\.\d{1,2})/\10/g' myFile.txt
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Use `sprintf()` with the `%f` format, which lets you specify the number of digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 2):

- `\1` should be `$1`. It makes no sense to use `\1` in the replacement expression. As indicated by a warning, doing so is a bug.
- It's seeing `$10` rather than `$1`. Use curlies to disambiguate (`${1}0`).
- That always adds one zero, even when you need two.

Solutions:

```
perl -i -pe's/\.\d(\d)?\K/ defined($1) ? "0" : "00" /eg' myFile.txt
perl -i -pe's/\.(\d{1,2})\K/ "0" x (3 - length($1)) /eg' myFile.txt
perl -i -pe's/\.\d(?!\d)\K/0/g; s/\.\d\d\K/0/g;' myFile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you I ended up using something very similar to this! Totally forgot I could use the $ sign instead of \

Comment: @Julian Fondren, I know. I even said as much. Why do you mention that?

Comment: @ikegami, OK, that's not a bug: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241

Answer (score 2):

As [Barmar said in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416311/perl-one-liner-to-specify-decimal-places#comment25293419_17416311), you can use `sprintf` to specify the number of decimal places.

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(\d+\.\d+)/sprintf "%.3f", $1/eg' myFile.txt
```

Notes:

- `%.3f` means a floating point number with 3 decimal places.
- `e` flag means evaluate the replacement side as an expression.
- Also note that you have to capture the entire number (not just digits after decimal point) for this to work.
- `$1` is used instead of `\1` on replacement side (see [perldoc note here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241) about this).